# Java code executing unexpected numbers

Tags: java

I have got the following Java code, and I wanted to understand the way how it calculates.

I know it prints out `1,1,0,0;` but according to my own "calculation", it is supposed to print out something like 3,4,10, of course my way of thinking must be wrong, but I am not too sure, what is my mistake.

Anyway the code is:

```
public class Q11aFrom2013 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] r = { 2, 3, 7, 12, 10 };
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length - 1; i++)
            System.out.println(f(r[i + 1]));
    }

    public static int f(int r) {
        return r % 2;
    }
}
```

Also I made notes of my own calculaton, feel free and check the following picture in order to see or find out and maybe inform me what I did wrong, thanks in advance:

[image]

Comment: You're returning the modulo of the number with 2 (`return r%2;`), so you'll only get 0 or 1 as a result. The code presented here should print the results of `3%2, 7%2, 12%2, 10%2` which are, respectively, `1, 1, 0, 0`.

Comment: It can only print 0, 1 (or -1 if you have negative odd numbers),  because you are printing the result of `whateverTheNumberIs%2`. So you cannot have a result like 3, 4 or 10 (or Java's math is seriously broken!!)

Comment: @ AntonH , thanks, I was confused that I might need to add 1 since System.out.println(f(r[i+1])) was saying +1, I guess I should ignore this whole sentence.

Comment: The `+1` references which element of the array you choose, nothing else. I looked at the notes and have no idea how you reached the values you show.

Comment: @AntonH , I guess I am a woman with many hidden talents in regards of maths & it :D No joking, I had a similar code, and I calculated it just the same way as in my notes and it worked in that particular code, so I assumed, that must have been the right way to do it in these sort of framents of codes, but of course I was wrong.

Comment: fwiw:  Modulo function x%n always returns values 0 to n-1.  x%4 returns 0, 1, 2, or 3.  x%3 returns 0,1 or 2.  And in your case, x%2 will give 0 or 1 (yeah, already been said, but just illustrating my example with it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes the r[i+1] value and print the modulo by 2.

So:

- first : `3 modulo 2 == 1` == 2 * 1 + **1**
- second : `7 modulo 2 == 1` == 2 * 3 + **1**
- third : `12 modulo 2 == 0` == 2 * 6 + **0**
- fourth : `10 modulo 2 == 0` == 2 * 5 + **0**

Comment: Wow, that is good, I will re-write my notes now, thank you :)

Comment: 1 more question, I have noticed it when I was writing down the answer you have given, how comes we ignored the very first element of the array r, which is number 2? Why did we jumped over it and started from 3?

Comment: @Acemi Because you are calling `f(r[i+1])`, so you will never call `f` method with the first element of the array (0 is the first index value). You call `f(r[1])`, `f(r[2])` etc. but never `f(r[0])`. To fix that, you have to change the loop: `for(int i=0; i<r.length; i++)` and call `f(r[i])`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that what you're returning is the **modulo** of the number you send there. That is the remainder of the number when divided by what is after the % (2 in your case).

So the only results you'll see are 1 for an odd number, 0 for an even (remainders of dividing by two).

Comment: If this helped you to figure out what was going on, please mark it as an answer so that other people will easily be able to figure out how to solve similar problems.